# Collection from a collection Lambda

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Considering the situation below, I need to get all of the bottom class level objects that belong to the list of middle objects assigned to the top level. The structure I have means that middle level objects hang off top level, but the bottom level is just a collection of all. Therefore I need to get all the bottom objects that effectively "hang off" the top and middle levels even though a list does not exist. Is there a nice way to do this in lambda?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<TopClass> topClasses = new List<TopClass>();

        List<MiddleClass> mcList1 = new List<MiddleClass>();
        mcList1.Add(new MiddleClass(1));
        mcList1.Add(new MiddleClass(3));
        mcList1.Add(new MiddleClass(5));
        TopClass tc1 = new TopClass(1, mcList1);
        topClasses.Add(tc1);

        List<MiddleClass> mcList2 = new List<MiddleClass>();
        mcList2.Add(new MiddleClass(2));
        mcList2.Add(new MiddleClass(4));
        TopClass tc2 = new TopClass(2, mcList2);
        topClasses.Add(tc2);

        List<MiddleClass> mcList3 = new List<MiddleClass>();
        mcList3.Add(new MiddleClass(6));
        mcList3.Add(new MiddleClass(7));
        TopClass tc3 = new TopClass(3, mcList3);
        // ** Note not added to the global list

        List<BottomClass> bottomClasses = new List<BottomClass>();
        bottomClasses.Add(new BottomClass(10, 1));
        bottomClasses.Add(new BottomClass(20, 2));
        bottomClasses.Add(new BottomClass(30, 3));
        bottomClasses.Add(new BottomClass(40, 4));
        bottomClasses.Add(new BottomClass(50, 5));
        bottomClasses.Add(new BottomClass(60, 6));
        bottomClasses.Add(new BottomClass(70, 7));

        bottomClass.FindAll(b => ....?
    }
}

public class TopClass //Instruments
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<MiddleClass> MiddleClasses { get; set; }

    public TopClass(int id, List<MiddleClass> middleClasses)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.MiddleClasses = middleClasses;
    }
}

public class MiddleClass // Sequences
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public MiddleClass(int id)
    {
        this.Id = id;
    }
}


public class BottomClass //SequenceItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MiddleClassId { get; set; }

    public BottomClass(int id, int middleClassId)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.MiddleClassId = middleClassId;
    }
}
```

The result would be a List containing 10 through 50 but not 60 and 70.

Comment: Could you post a class structure summary for the classes. Do you only want "Bottom Classes" to be filtered? I can't see what properties to include in the lambada.

EDIT : Just saw the class structure :)

Comment: All your bottom class reference a middle class, and all middle class hang off top class so surely all bottom class hang off a top/middle class

Comment: @saj but if you look the middle class doesn't have a direct reference to either topclass or bottom class so there is no distinct chain to follow

Comment: That's right Bob, it's a kind of inferred chain. Not the best structure I know but play the cards your dealt and all that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How About

```
topClasses
 .SelectMany(x=>x.MiddleClasses)
 .SelectMany(x=>bottomClasses.Where(y=>y.MiddleClassId==x.Id))
```

Optionally add `.Distinct()` on the end for uniqueness

Or from the other way

```
bottomClasses.Where(
  b=>topClasses.Any(t=>t.MiddleClasses.Any(m=>m.Id==b.MiddleClassId))
)
```

Comment: Thanks, the second solution was exactly what I was after with the inclusion of a ToList().

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you were going for...

```
var test = bottomClasses.Where(b => b.Id >= 10 && b.Id <= 50);
```

If not please comment what I have mis-interpreted :)

Comment: OP asked for a specific filter and indicated that 10-50 would be the right answer for this specific case

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want. So given a TopClass e.g. tc3, this will give you all the bottom classes hanging off tc3

```
   var allMiddleClasses = topClasses.SelectMany(t => t.MiddleClasses);

    var allBC = 
            bottomClasses
                .Where(b => allMiddleClasses.Select(m => m.Id).Contains(b.MiddleClassId))
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks saj, except this returns 60 and 70, but not 10 through 50; how would I invert it?